# Flutter: Unable to run app in debug mode in chrome

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

i wanna run flutter web app on chrome in debug mode but whenever i try so, i get this error

> Failed to establish connection with the application instance in Chrome.
> This can happen if the websocket connection used by the web tooling is unable to correctly establish a connection, for example due to a firewall.

but release mode works properly using

> flutter run -d chrome --release

i have tried;

> flutter clean.

> flutter pub cache repair

> switching to master channel

> disabling firewalls

But none of these worked. I seriously need to run the app in debug mode for troubleshooting.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can make it work with these steps: 1) Clean your project, 2) Clear your app's cache (`flutter pub cache repair`) 3) Run your project using release mode, 4) Run your project using debug mode

Comment: It didn’t work for me ☹️

Answer (score 0):

You have to download Dart Debug Extension on Google Chrome to run flutter app on chrome through your editor

Comment: This extension is needed only if you run the app as web server, flutter run -d web-server

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, too.
Then, I disconnected my VPN and started debugging. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error kept popping up randomly. I would run `flutter clean` but that only worked for a few runs then the problem came back.
I decided to use Edge and so far I haven't seen the problem again.

```
flutter run -d edge
```